# Shell - Start 10,000 process in Centos 7 and each process log to different file

Tags: linux, shell, nohup

I want to start 10,000 process, each of them is a build of mqtt client coding with Clang, and each of them log to different file when receive message, but when I run this shell script, it blocked at 999. See original code `v1.sh`, it won't stuck if I change it to `v2.sh`.
I've tried modify the linux kernel configuration as [System tunning - EMQ X Broker](https://docs.emqx.io/broker/latest/en/tutorial/tune.html) says.

and in additional, in `/etc/security/limits.conf` I've added

```
 * soft nproc   1048576
 * hard nproc   1048576
```

So, How can I modify the config to make it(start 10,000 process and each of them log to different file) working?

- v1.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
a=1
start_topic=1
echo "$1"
while [ $a -le "$1" ]; do
  ((Num = $a % 1000))
  if [ $Num == 0 ]; then
    ((start_topic++))
  else
    command="nohup ./stdoutsub channel_$start_topic  --host example_host --port 1883 --username example_username --password example_password --clientid test_3.3_$a >nohup.out &"
    eval "$command"
    printf "%s start completed\n" $a
    a=$((a + 1))
    sleep 0.1
  fi
done
```

- v2.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
a=1
start_topic=1
echo "$1"
while [ $a -le "$1" ]; do
  ((Num = $a % 1000))
  if [ $Num == 0 ]; then
    ((start_topic++))
  else
    command="nohup ./stdoutsub channel_$start_topic  --host example_host --port 1883 --username example_username --password example_password --clientid test_3.3_$a >nohup_$a.out &"
    eval "$command"
    printf "%s start completed\n" $a
    a=$((a + 1))
    sleep 0.1
  fi
done
```

Comment: Did you restart your shell after making the ulimit changes?

Comment: @RamanSailopal sure, I restarted.